# boost interprocess vector slower than std::vector

Tags: c++, boost, stl, ipc, shared-memory

I'm doing a benchmark on `boost::interprocess:vector` and `std::vector`, since I'm gonna use shared memory in my program but I'm concerned with any potential performance issues.

My benchmark is simply random accessing a vector, and it turned out that `std::vector` is almost 2x faster than `boost::interprocess::vector`.

Note: in the benchmark I only have a single process, and I don't do any synchronization manually.

I don't know where is the bottleneck....I have three guess:

1. shared memory make it slower
2. boost vector has a slower implementation
3. boost shared memory as well as its containers have some overhead somehow, i.e., if I use `mmap` and do things in a plain way, it will be better

And what further experiment should I do to figure out this? Or tune something to make it faster? Any idea?

---

Here is the benchmark code:

for `boost::interprocess::vector`

```
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::interprocess;


typedef allocator<double, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;
typedef vector<double, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;

const int total_size = 2000 * 2000;
const int mem_size = 2000 * 2000 * 8 * 2;
const int query_size = 100000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0, 10000);
  std::default_random_engine re;

  std::vector<double> data;
  data.reserve(total_size);
  for (int i = 0; i < total_size; ++i) {
    data.push_back(unif(re));
  }
  std::vector<int> query;
  query.reserve(query_size);
  for (int i = 0; i < query_size; ++i) {
    query.push_back(rand() % total_size);
  }

  struct shm_remove {
    shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
    ~shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
  } remover;


  managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", mem_size);

  const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment.get_segment_manager());

  MyVector *myvector = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);
  myvector->reserve(total_size);

  for (auto d : data) myvector->push_back(d);

  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (auto q : query) {
    double res = (*myvector)[q];
  }
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

for `std::vector`

```
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>  //std::system
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const int total_size = 2000 * 2000;
const int mem_size = 2000 * 2000 * 8 * 8;
const int query_size = 100000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0, 10000);
  std::default_random_engine re;

  std::vector<double> data;
  data.reserve(total_size);
  for (int i = 0; i < total_size; ++i) {
    data.push_back(unif(re));
  }
  std::vector<int> query;
  query.reserve(query_size);
  for (int i = 0; i < query_size; ++i) {
    query.push_back(rand() % total_size);
  }
  std::vector<double> myvector;
  myvector.reserve(total_size);

  for (auto d : data) myvector.push_back(d);

  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (auto q : query) {
    double res = myvector[q];
  }
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I imagine the shared one would have a lot of synchronization overhead. Does it have to acquire a lock every time you access it?

Comment: @Shawn Currently in the benchmark I only have a single process, so actually I don't do any synchronization

Comment: Are you sure about that? The interprocess vector code isn't acquiring any locks internally?

Comment: That isn't a very good benchmark.  The compiler is likely to optimize out your entire loop since `res` is unused.  If I change `res` to be `volatile` to force the compiler to actually do something for it I get almost the exact same time from both.

Comment: The best you can do is to use the standard vector along with some OS dependant synchronization.

Comment: First thing is first: did you build executable in release mode with optimizations enabled? Are you sure that you want to measure indirect access to shared vector through pointer?